# Colour value of TextBox vanishes after JS function is executed in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, xhtml

The colour property of TexBox vanishes (blinks) when property is set through the below JS function. Please advice, how to retain the colour property?

(i.e once the button is clicked the colour (green for odd and red for even) blinks and colour goes back to blank)

```js
function numbercheck() {
  var num = document.getElementById("txtnum").value;

  if (num == "") {
    alert("Please Enter number")
  } else {
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      alert("You have entered even number");
      document.getElementById("txtnum").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
      alert("You have enetered Odd number");
      document.getElementById("txtnum").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p> Please enter a Number :
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtnum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<asp:Button Text="Check Number" ID="btnnum" runat="server" OnClientClick="return numbercheck()" />
```

Comment: The button triggers a PostBack, and then changes made to the DOM are lost.

Comment: `OnClientClick="numbercheck(); return false;"` will prevent button to postback. Thus you will retain textbox colour property.

Comment: ...or you do a `return false` in the numbercheck function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Please change your script function as
      function numbercheck() {
                debugger;
                var num = document.getElementById("<%=txtnum.ClientID%>").value;

                if (num == "") {
                    alert("Please Enter number")
                } else {
                    if (num % 2 == 0) {
                        alert("You have entered even number");
                        document.getElementById("<%=txtnum.ClientID%>").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                    } else {`enter code here`
                        alert("You have enetered Odd number");
                        document.getElementById("<%=txtnum.ClientID%>").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    }
                }
            }

and 
<asp:Button Text="Check Number" ID="btnnum" runat="server" OnClientClick="return numbercheck()"  CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```